# How to get VSTest 15 to ignore all xUnit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, mstest, xunit, vstest

I have a mixture of xUnit and MSTest tests in a few assemblies. I have a program that runs the xUnit tests with the xUnit console runner and it runs the MSTest tests with the VSTest console runner.

In VSTest 14 (Visual Studio 2015) this wasn't a problem because it ignored all xUnit tests. However in VSTest 15 (Visual Studio 2017) it finds and runs all the xUnit tests and runs them very slowly. Ideally I would like to have the xUnit console runner run just the xUnit tests and the VSTest console runner run just the MSTest tests.

Is there a way to have VSTest 15 ignore the xUnit tests?

(And no, the namespace, class and method names don't distinguish between xUnit and MSTest, so filtering is very tough)